# Screen mirroring android things (RPI) with TeamViewer Host

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, android-things, teamviewer

I've succeeded to screen mirror the RPI running android things. What I did is:

- installed TeamViewer_Host.apk via adb
- Ran it on the RPI and login to my account(needed a display connected by HDMI)
- connected to it by my laptop TeamViewer application
- then got a very nice 1080p resolution mirrored screen

But the problem appeared when I tried to do the same thing but without the HDMI display connected and then suddenly got a poor 32x32 tiny screen on the laptop!

I tried it with Vysor app too but got the same result

My guess is that Android Things somehow detects automatically the resolution of the display and fits itself with it but when there's no display connected, it gives us a 32x32 one!

You guys have any ideas for this one?

Comment: Please file a feature request with this information on our issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192720&template=848805

Comment: feature request? it looks more like a bug issue doesn't it?

Comment: The current behavior is as designed to optimize the system with no display connected. So a change to that behavior would be a Feature Request to change the current system design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I finally got the right way to do this.

The only thing you need to do is to adjust the resolution(while your Pi is connected to an HDMI display). After that you dont need the physical display any more and can connect to the Pi via TeamViewer.

For adjusting the resolution use this command in ADB:`adb shell wm size 1080x1920` or any other resolution.