# raspberry pi screen mirroring performance

Tags: android, android-things

I've built a version of Android Things on a Raspberry Pi 3B and have been experimenting with screen mirroring apps (e.g. Airscreen, CASTReceiver, etc.).  The performance is pretty bad.  If I use Emteria or LineageOS 16 as the OS rather than Android Things, the performance is fine.  Does anyone know why this is?  It's my understanding that Android Things is using the hardware acceleration capabilities of the GPU on the Raspberry Pi and I've confirmed that the apps I'm using have hardware acceleration enabled.

Comment: Does this relate? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47237639/5184092

Comment: No.  It's just referring to issues with the resolution.  I'm trying to improve the performance of the video streaming.